# Django ChoiceField RadioSelect widget in form, test whitch element selected in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, radio-button, choicefield

I have 2 radio buttons in a ChoiceField and I would like to display some parts of the template, depending of witch radio button is selected.

Following :

- form.py

> ```
>  class CtdForm(forms.Form):
>     protocol_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
>     rb = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='RB')
>     mr = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='MR')
>     CHOICES = [('rb' ,'RB'), ('mr', 'MR')]
>     analyse_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
> ```

- template html

> ```
> ...  
> {{ form.analyse_type }}  
> Here I would like to test which button is selected and display the template depending of the selection 
> something like : {% if form.analyse_type.? == true %} 
> ...
> ```

I test a lot of syntaxe with form.analyse_type.? like form.analyse_type.field.widget.choices to have each choices in a loop ect. , but I do not found the right one returning the selected radiobutton...

Maybe this way is not the right one to do what I want.

If you have any idea, solution thank you ;)

***Edit for user2497126***
Thanks for all tips :) !

I have an error Uncaught Error: GET_ELEMENTS:  -> form[data-sb-form-api-token] seems to be in link with the object analyse_type

As requested, following a print screen with the html element.I tired different synthaxe like

> let radioValue =$("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").value();

[image]

I also put my HTML code in case

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div style="padding-left: 30%;" class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6"
    <h2 class="h4 fw-bolder">
        Analyse Type
    </h2>
    <br>
        {{ form.analyse_type }}
    <br> </div> 
    <div id="template-one" style="display:none;">
       <div style="padding-right: 30%;" class="col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
        <h2 class="h4 fw-bolder">
            TEST
        </h2> 
     </div>  
  </div> 
 {% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}  
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".custom-control-input").change(function () {
                let radioValue = $("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").value();
                let templateOne = document.getElementById('template-one')
                if (radioValue == "rb") {
                    $("#template-one").show();
                } else {
                    $("#template-one").hide();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>


{% endblock javascript %}
```

***EDIT***

if I do a

> console.log($("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").val())

in the debugger of chrome I have a return of rb.
But the error is still there with no result.
I also change the html, include the template-one in the same div of the form like your example
The problem seems here

> $(".custom-control-input").change(function () {

I replace .custom by select or select#id_analyse_type, based on some forum answers, but I have no result

Thanks for your time and your help :)

***EDIT***

Here the solution :

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let radioValue = $("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").val();
                if (radioValue == "rb") {
                    $("#template-one").show();
                } else {
                    $("#template-one").hide();
                }
            $('#id_analyse_type').change(function () {
                let radioValue = $("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").val();
                if (radioValue == "rb") {
                    $("#template-one").show();
                } else {
                    $("#template-one").hide();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited answer which I have tried to adapt to your question

For the change function (i.e when selecting the radio) inspect and replace the class value with the one in your radio input. Also ensure you supply the correct name when instantiating the variable radioValue, I have used 'analyze_type' for the sake of the example but inspect and confirm the correct name value of the radio input.

You can achieve it using JS like this in your template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Form title{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}

<!-- page content -->

                    <div class="x_content">
                        {{ form.analyse_type}}
                        <div id="template-one" style="display:none;">
                            Template one
                        </div>
                        <div id="template-two" style="display:none;">
                            Template two
                        </div>

                    </div>
<!-- /page content -->
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".custom-control-input").change(function(){
                let radioValue = $("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").val();
                let templateOne = document.getElementById('template-one')
                if(radioValue == "RB"){
                    $("#template-one").show();
                    $("#template-two").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#template-two").show();
                    $("#template-one").hide();
                }
            });     
        });
        
    </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Comment: it is not working. Nothing appears I tried also form.get_analyse_display (rename analyse_type by analyse) but nothing

Comment: I also tired to put a function in form to call it in template but I do not find the way to check witch element is selected

Comment: Check out the edited answer. I have tried it in one of my forms and it works. If it works for you as well kindly accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not know a lot about JS, I do an auto formation following : https://javascript.info/, but I have only done the first part. I understand it but from sratch it is still hard to do...

Comment: It is not still working. Indeed, I do not use crispy (I have a module not found but the module with pip3 is intalled ...) so I remove it. I do not think so this is the source of the problem but juste in case I mention it.

Comment: Nothing is done when I select the first or the second. I think this is a problem with analyse_type; exactly $("input[name='analyse_type']:checked").val(). Indeed, analyse_type seems not to be directly the radio button ... I do not find a way to have access to it... I do not understand the structure, even I read the documentation

Comment: I used code from my project to write the answer so that is why it contains crispy. However, crispy is totally optional so just omit it. I have edited it out of the code

Comment: To find out the name and class of your radio is easy. While on your browser CTRL+SHIFT+I which will lead you to developer tools. To inspect your radio button CTRL+SHIFT+C and move the cursor to the radio input and click on it. This will display the element attributes on the developer tool and you can get the class and name. If the method described is challenging, the easiest will be to right click then view page source. Find your radio button to see the class and name attributes. I can help you identify the correct class and name if you can paste the HTML of your radio on your question.